# AR(1) on autocorrelated data that is not a time-series

Tags: regression, autocorrelation

I need to apply a regression model on observations that is not time series data but each observation presents a store and the amount of cartons that gets sent to that store. For  instance `a_i = number of cartons sent to store i` and is my dependent variable. Each carton contains products of different kinds and my independent variables is the number of units for a certain product for each observation. Thus `x_ij = number of units of product j sent to store i`. So essentially i need to forecast the number of cartons given the amount of units of each product that needs to go to a store.

The problem i have is that the data is autocorrelated, where smaller carton forecast tend to have bigger errors and larger carton forecast smaller errors. I would like to use AR(1) to transform the data with the following formula,

`Y_t - pY_(t-1) = B_0(1-p) + B_1(X_t - pX_(t-1))`

My model will have more than one independent variable, but it is correct of me to first sort the data ascending according to the dependent variable `a_i` before applying the above formula as `i` does not represent time but rather a store?

Answer (score 2):

AR(p) is a time series model, I don't see how and why would you apply it to your case.

If you think that the error depends on the size, then you are talking about [heteroscedasticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity) not the [autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation). The latter happens when your observations come in a certain order (not necessarily in time) and their noise is correlated with each other, the former happens when observations have different variance and there's no ordering involved.

Your packages are not observed according to their size, like small packages are weighed first. If your packages were observed this way, then you could talk about autocorrelation.

In presense of heteroscedasticty you can keep using OLS, but the parameter covariances will be messed, which I don't think you care about much. If you want to adjust for this problem, then use so called [hac](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/hac.html) estimators. The popular one is [Newey-West](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newey%E2%80%93West_estimator) estimator, which can adjust for both autocorrelation and heteroscedasticity